# Team City Prevent Build Step From Running

Tags: c#, msbuild, nunit, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am working setting up my continuous integration server using Teamcity and I have three steps for my build (.NET/VS2010/MSBUILD)

1. Use MSBUILD to build my solution.
2. Run NUnit Tests.
3. Use MSBUILD to do a Web deploy of my projects.

The issue I am trying to solve is to prevent step 3 from running if any of the test fail.  Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not appear that this is possible at this time using teamcity http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-12194

Comment: If your tests fail, does your build fail?  If not, that's where I'd concentrate.  Once you have that working you could opt to push the web deploy into a separate build that is dependent on your actual build.  I prefer that option as I think they're independent processes, and should succeed/fail separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [NUnit MsBuild Community task](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) by handling Output parameter "ExitCode" and then executing MSBuild [Error Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b08t3s4.aspx) depends on "ExitCode" or execute Deploy task/targets depends on this condition, so it is up to you.

> **Error task:**
>
> Stops a build and logs an error based on an evaluated conditional statement.
>   The Error task allows MSBuild projects issue error text to loggers and stop build execution

```xml
<!-- Build -->
<Build .... />

<!-- Run tests -->
<Nunit ....>
   <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" 
           PropertyName="NUnitResult" />

<!-- Stop build in case of error whilst tests run -->    
<Error Text="Tests failed"
       Code="$(NUnitResult)"
       Condition="'$(NUnitResult)' != '0'"/>

<!-- Deploy -->    
<Deploy Condition="'$(NUnitResult)' != '0'"/ ... />
```

Comment: Right now I am using multiple build steps in TeamCity.  So while the build could fail, all steps in the process would be executed.  I was hoping to do it all in the MSBuild file, however I could not find documentation on a build task that would run the Web Deploy publishing.  I was going to possibly try running MSDeploy.exe using the Exec task.